# How to hide the controller in cakrphp

Tags: cakephp

i have give role in database where one role is admin and other is store..when store will login he will not able to see any controller except store..i.e. i want to hide all controller and show only one controller when store will login in cakephp and my code is

```
public function isAuthorized($customer) {
    $role = $customer['role'];
    if(in_array($this->action,array('other controllers'))){
            if($role != 'admin'){
                return false;

            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but this is not working..

Comment: i know a way , which is not clean , do you want it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way cause i don't the ACL way :

i create a beforeFilter function in all my controllers , and in there i check the role's user stored in the session , and i redirect if the user is not allowed to that controller :

```
function beforeFilter(){
        $role = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role');
        if($role=="simple") $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'store','action' => 'index'));
}
```